# error in filtered function creation on couchdb

Tags: couchdb

I'm trying to follow this tutorial to filter the replication between a pouchdb and a couchdb databases

https://pouchdb.com/2015/04/05/filtered-replication.html

The problem is when I try to create the filtered function in the Fauxton webapp. In my created database, I click Design Document > New Docs and then paste the function:

```
  {
     "_id": "_design/app",
     "filters": {
       "by_agent": function(doc, req) {
         return doc.agent === req.query.agent;
       }.toString()
     }
  }
```

and when I click Create Document button, it crashes. The javascript console says

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 61
    at JSON.parse ()
    at t.checkDocIsValid (https://127.0.0.1:6984/_utils/dashboard.assets/js/bundle-b8e0ba71119195edb7ec64b98f53d9b9.js:529:19481)
    at t.saveDoc (https://127.0.0.1:6984/_utils/dashboard.assets/js/bundle-b8e0ba71119195edb7ec64b98f53d9b9.js:529:19056)
...

how do I create the filtered function in couchDB? Maybe that isn't the procedure or I have to create it on another dababase. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So what you're trying to do is use JavaScript code to create a view. Therefore, Fauxton takes only JSON as a document.

Here's how you can get the JSON from the JavaScript snippet :

```js
//The snippet you had was a JavaScript object
//Even if it seems like a JSON object, there is a function() declaration followed by a .toString()
//By doing so, it easier to write functions instead of writing them in a raw string.

var javascriptObject = {
     "_id": "_design/app",
     "filters": {
       "by_agent": function(doc, req) {
         return doc.agent === req.query.agent;
       }.toString()
     }
  }
  console.info("You should use the following string in your Fauxton Editor:");
  console.log(JSON.stringify(javascriptObject));
```

You should use the following string instead of the JavaScript snippet you tried:

```
{
  "_id": "_design/app",
  "filters": {
    "by_agent": "function (doc, req) {\n         return doc.agent === req.query.agent;\n       }"
  }
}
```